# How can I satisfy a part testing contract?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I've been flying a few contracts now that the contracts update has been released.  I notice in my contract bar that all of the checkmarks for a contract are green, however I am not awarded the contract completion.

Specifically in contracts where the request is "test this engine at this height at this altitude" if I wait until I land and recover the vessel, the checkmarks for the contract go back to clocks rather than checks, indicating that the game is still waiting for the objectives to be completed.

Is there some method to claim the contract from the air or otherwise trigger "Hey, I'm done this!" so that those types of contracts will complete?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To satisfy a contract you must activate the stage with the component to be tested while all the check marks are green.  The check marks simply indicate that the conditions are right to start the test.  Once you activate the stage you should be awarded the contract and that is instant.  Recovery of the vehicle is not required for the contract, although you do recover funds.

Comment: Ah!  I didn't realize that you had to **engage** the part at the given conditions, I thought it just had to be running at the time.  That solved it.  Thank you!

Comment: Would it have KILLED them to add that to the contract ? (activate part when all conditions are met?)

Comment: Some parts require to activate the part from the right-click menu, pick "run test".

Answer (score 9):

For most part tests, activating the stage with the part when the exact conditions are met is enough to fulfill the conditions. However, in some cases the test has to be run by right-clicking on the part and choosing "run test".

This usually applies to parts which are not involved in staging (I had to do this with a small gear bay I had to test in orbit), but I also had this when I had to test the LV-N engine in orbit. The conditions were met, I activated the stage with the engine, and the contract wasn't fulfilled. Then I right-clicked the engine and picked "run test" and the contract was fulfilled.

Comment: Interesting, I'll have to check this out.  I wonder if there's a way to trigger "Run Test" from action group.  Worthy of a test!

Answer (score -1):

Objective: To test the AE-FF2 and the AE-FF3 Airstream Protective Shell **splashed down at Kerbin** ...

Me: I launched enough failed craft to go looking for a solution (here). It turns out, I had over-complicated the task. I used the part in many ways, places, and stages; like how I thought the part would be used. After watching a video of a rocket engine being fired 'Splashed down in the water' I tried to keep it simple.

I launched a shell with a parachute, splashed down (check) on Kerbin (check), and " Activated the part **through the staging sequence** (space bar) while in the water (check) and DONE!